# What is the use of the view.xml of theme etc directory

Tags: magento2, theme, xml, luma-theme, media-images

I found this file located in the `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml`
Can we depend on this file to make change to the image resolution?

Any other specific use of this file. 
Shall we put any color variables in this file and load on theme level.

Comment: Please if there is full sample of this file, thanks

Answer (score 5):

In this file you can configure some properties related with FE.

E.g size of the images of prodcuts on the overview list. You can also add here a custom ID of image with your own size and generate picture in PHP

Additionally, you can set some properties without override templates files like

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
        <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

This example change behavior of gallery for configurable prodcuts. So sometimes instead override the template file, you can reach your goal by this file

Comment: other from the comments in the view.xml file (that can be sometimes confusing) is there somewhere a listing to describe each property available to customize ? Thank's

Comment: I am not sure if there is any official doc for it, but you can check list of properties in "vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml"